# custom cell data not displayed ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to display the cell data. Actually if I debug the code I can see that the `cell.label.text` does have correct value, but nothing is getting displayed on the simulator. I have set the row count in numberOfRowsInSection method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
        LogTableCell *cell = (LogTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        CGRect frame1 = [ self.view  frame];
        frame1.origin.x=22.0f;
        frame1.origin.y=55.0f;

        frame1.size.width = 298.0f;
        frame1.size.height= 425.0f;
        [self.view.superview setFrame:frame1];
        int btnWidth = ((self.view.frame.size.width-16)/3);


        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[LogTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }
        LogItem *lg = [[LogItem alloc]init];

        lg = [arrLogs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
        cell.lblname.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.lblsubtype.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.lbltime.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.lblname.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Merriweather" size:15.0];
        cell.lblsubtype.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Merriweather-Light" size:13.0];
        cell.lbltime.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Merriweather-Light" size:13.0];

        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, cell.contentView.frame.size.height, 298.0,2)] ;

        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"lineseperator.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview];

        cell.lblname.text = lg.name;
        NSLog(@"%@",lg.name);
        [[cell imgtype] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:lg.imagetype]];

        if([lg.subtype length] == 0){
            NSLog(@"%@",lg.subtype);
            cell.lblsubtype.text = lg.time;
            cell.lbltime.text = @"";
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%@",lg.subtype);
            cell.lblsubtype.text = lg.subtype;
            cell.lbltime.text = lg.time;
        }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating your cell's labels? Your question refers to `cell.label.text` but I don't see this anywhere in your code. Also, a friendly tip to maximize your code's readability - familiarize yourself with [this great document here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html).

Comment: cell.label.text is an example.Actually I meant all the labels as cell.lblname.text,cell.lblsubtype.text,cell.lbltime.text

Answer (score 0):

The imageview you're adding to the cell is covering all other content. You'll need to either resize/reposition it, or just use the already existing cell.imageView instead.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen - it's only two pixels high and at the bottom of the cell.

Comment: Yes its just 2 pixels high ,its a lineseperator.